# NoReverseMatch in django when trying without hardcoding

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a music app which has the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),

]
```

and in my html code I called this

```
<form action="{%  url 'music:favorite' album_id %}" method="post">
```

Then I am getting NoReverseMatch exception.

```
Reverse for 'favorite' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['music/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$']
```

Comment: It means that `album_id` is empty.

Comment: Is `album_id` defined in your template context?

Comment: Sorry that was the error album_id not defined in my template context